# Generate more space between barcodes using iText 5.4.1

Tags: itext, barcode

im using itext 5.4 to generate some 128 type barcode, but i am strugling to find any way to generate the barcode bar with more space between them. could anyone help? I tried lots of itext options, but none of them worked.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
 Barcode barcode = new Barcode128();
 barcode.setBarHeight(50);
 barcode.setCode(text);
 Image img = barcode.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
 BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), 
 img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
 Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
 g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried that, but it didn't work, what I had to do was call the method img.getScaledDefinition, or somethind like that, passing in the new width of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine `setX()` is what you're looking for.